# Нужна ли тут запятая? (3)

Tags: пунктуация

*В прошлом году(,) нынешний 11 "В"...*

Comment: Отвечающий прав, запятую ставят по-английски в предложениях типа ‘In 1980, <...>’, а по-русски — нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В большинстве случаев не нужна, хотя в некоторых случаях, в зависимости от контекста, может оказаться нужна. В простых предложениях типа *"В прошлом году нынешний 11 класс ездил на соревнования"* запятой не надо. Использование запятой в таких случаях -- частая и очень раздражающая ошибка.